# Remote Debugging on Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, remote-debugging, windows-server-2012

I'm currently developing a WPF-Program which is running on an external server.
I now have installed the Remote Debugger both on the server and on my notebook.

For my tests, I don't install this program, just to save time .. but is there a chance, to Debug the *.exe file which is copied to the server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Debug->Attach to process in VS menu.In the opened dialog inside Connection target box  find your remote server through IP or hostname. It will show the exe running on server (if you have run VS remote debugger MSVSMON.EXE running on server machine) .Click on attach button and then you can debug the exe.